# Loop through all h2 elements and add unique id

Tags: jquery

I need to add unique ids to all h2 tags with jquery. I dont know how to add unique ids actually all of my h2 tags get the same when i just use the attr function and i have no idea how to change that.

```
$('h2').attr("id", "rev3");
```

Comment: What have  you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use an implicit function inside jQuerys `.each()` like this

```
var id = 0;
$('h2').each(function(){
    $(this).attr("id", "rev" + id);
    id++;
})
```

`.each()` loops through all result array elements, while `this` reffers always to the current element.

Comment: You don't even need `each`. You can pass function to `attr` itself `$('h2').attr('id', x => \`rev${x}\`)`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko That is also a beautiful solution!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with  each. You don't even need a seperate variable to hold the index:

```
$('h2').each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).attr('id', 'anid' + index);
});
```

Comment: You're totally right. I assumed a more complex id generation while writing my example...

Comment: Hi, I am bit late, I was wondering, is there a way in which I can run this on h2  just within an <article> tag?